# Parse raw binary file for multiple sets of video frames

Tags: python, parsing, multiplexing

I am trying to parse a raw binary file in Python with known headers and lengths.

The data is a 6 channel multiplexed video.

The file follows the following rules to separate frames:

- Byte 1:  Indicates the channel # (eg 0xE0, 0xE1, 0xE2 ...)
- Bytes 4 & 5: Represent the length of the image data
- Bytes 6: Length: Image data
- The end of the image data is padded with 0xFF so that every image chunk starts on the first byte in 16-byte rows.

Beginning of image data

```
E0 01 00 00 D2 59 80 C1 27 3F EC BB 31 7B 3F EC 

BB 31 7B 0F 9B 90 5D A8 81 AA 5F A9 C1 D2 4B B9

9D 0A 8D 1B 8F 89 44 FF 4E 86 92 AD 00 90 5B A8
```

End of image data

```
67 49 0B B5 BC 82 38 AE 5E 46 49 86 6A FF 24 97 

69 8C 6F 17 6D 67 B5 11 C7 E5 FB E3 3F 65 1F 22 

5C F3 7C D0 7C 49 2F CD 26 37 4D 40 FF FF FF FF
```

The source files are several GB large. What is the best way to parse each channel into a separate file? Also, how can I batch process several files at once, saving the files according to the input name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing tiny chunks of multi-GB binary files is probably not something Python is going to be very fast at, as it will require a ton of function calls and object creation, meaning a lot of RAM and CPU overhead. If you need more performance or control over memory management, it's probably best to do this in a lower-level language (C, C++, Go, Rust).

However, you can do this kind of thing in Python using the [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module, something like this:

```
header = struct.Struct('>BBBH')
data = b'\xE0\x01\x00\x00\xD2\x59\x80...'  # read this from input file
view = memoryview(data)
offset = 0
while offset < len(data):
    channel, _, _, length = header.unpack(view[offset:offset + header.size])
    write_output(channel, view[header.size:header.size + length])
    offset += length
```

Things to note:

- Determine whether the length is in big endian or little endian (`<` vs `>` in the format string)
- Using the [memoryview](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) is a way to avoid some of the extra object copying and creation -- hopefully it makes this more efficient
- You'll want to keep the output file(s) open -- I've just hidden this behind `write_output()` above
- If the input is multi-GB, you probably want to read the input file in chunks of 1MB or something sensible, rather than all at once
- Be careful about bytes vs strings (different handling on Python 2.x vs 3.x)
- If you need to know more about opening, reading, and writing files, feel free to post more specific questions

As far as batch processing several files at once, your best bet there is the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module. It does take a while to get your head around, but after that it's pretty simple to use.

Comment: What would you suggest to use in C++?

Comment: I've never used iostreams in C++ extensively, so personally I'd probably do it in C and just use fopen(), fread() with an unsigned char (byte) buffer. Reading 64KB or 1MB at a time or something.